# javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to refresh a table when $(.excluir) is clicked. The table is load from php data. When I click the button, the php code executes, and I delete the data from the database. 
But I want to refresh the content of the table. So, I tried to call the function again `completeTable();`, but it didn't work.. The alert appears, but the table doesn't refresh.

```
function completeTable(){
    $.post("completa_tabela.php", {cd_turma: $('#turma').val()}, function(data){

        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(data.json, function(){
            var button = "<button type='button' class='excluir' value='" + this['codigo'] + "'>X</button>";
            $('#' + this['dia_hora']).html(this['nome'] + button);
        });

        $('.excluir').click(function(){
            $.post("altera_horario.php", {excluir: true, cd_horario: $(this).val()}, function(){
                alert("$('excluir').click");
                    completeTable();
            });

        });

    });
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yours is not a recursive function. In your code you are **creating elements dynamically and binding events**.

You can use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  You should use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Change your code as

```
function completeTable(){
    $.post("completa_tabela.php", {cd_turma: $('#turma').val()}, function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data.json, function(){
            var button = "<button type='button' class='excluir' value='" + this['codigo'] + "'>X</button>";
            $('#' + this['dia_hora']).html(this['nome'] + button);
        });         
    });
}

$(document).on('click','.excluir', function(){
    $.post("altera_horario.php", {excluir: true, cd_horario: $(this).val()}, function(){
        alert("$('excluir').click");
            completeTable();
    });     
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think that if I do like that, the event won't be recognized, because `'.excluir'` class hasn't been created yet... will it?

Comment: @user3260711, I have used [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). So it will work for current as well as elements added in future

Comment: You were right, I didn't know it. But I'm still with the same problem.. The php code executes, the data is deleted, I call `completeTable()` and the content isn't reloaded.

Comment: @user3260711, What do you get when do an alert of `$('#turma').val()`

Comment: Thanks man, I figured out what was going on. The function was executing normally. But it only changes the content of the `<td>'s` when the `<td>'s` id is returned from the php code. So, when I delete the data, the id of that specific data doesn't return anymore, so the table isn't modified, and the data is still in the table.

Answer (score -1):

please use `$('.excluir').bind('click', function(){});` instead of `$('.excluir').click(function(){});`

you can also use `$('.excluir').live('click', function(){});`

Comment: -1: This does not address the OP's question, and `.bind` and `.live` have been deprecated since jQuery 1.7.